# in R how do I easily find the first x instances of a varibale in a table, ideally using dplyr?

Tags: r, sorting, mean

I have the following dataframe

```
ID <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3,3)
reversal = c('R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 
             'R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1',
             'R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R0', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2', 'R2')
event <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1) 

RT = runif(27)
df <- data.frame(ID, reversal, event, RT)
```

and I would like to identify/label for each `ID` and for each `reversal` the first 4 instances of 0 and the first 4 instances of 1 in `event`, so that I could, for example, calculate the mean RT for those first 4 instances of 0 and 1. Thank you!

Comment: consider using a seed and adding the final results to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by putting the logic directly into the `filter` statement, no need to `mutate` or create intermediate objects:

```
df %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 4, .by = c(ID, reversal, event)) %>%
  summarise(mean_RT = mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(ID, reversal, event))
```

Or in older versions of dplyr

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, reversal, event) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 4) %>%
  summarise(mean_RT = mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Both will give you the same output as your `mean_values`:

```
   ID reversal event    mean_RT
1   1       R0     0 0.53447121
2   1       R1     1 0.64449169
3   1       R1     0 0.91095299
4   2       R0     0 0.78950270
5   2       R1     1 0.33560007
6   2       R1     0 0.89449568
7   3       R0     0 0.70057488
8   3       R1     1 0.31019288
9   3       R1     0 0.49802194
10  3       R2     1 0.05643762
11  3       R2     0 0.07677300
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution

```
library(dplyr)

# Step 1: Flag the first 4 instances of 0 and 1 for each ID and reversal
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, reversal, event) %>%
  mutate(event_instance = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Flag only the first 4 instances of each event type
df$event_instance <- ifelse(df$event_instance <= 4, df$event_instance, NA)

# Step 2: Calculate the mean RT for these identified instances
mean_values <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(event_instance)) %>%
  group_by(ID, reversal, event) %>%
  summarise(mean_RT = mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE))

print(mean_values)
```